# How to manage a changing List while performing enumeration?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, enumeration

I have a list of objects (musical notes) that is enumerated on a separate thread as they are played.  I am doing this so that I can keep the UI thread responsive.

whilst a note is playing (as part of an enumeration) how can I allow for the fact that a new note may of been added to the List (without the obvious collection modified exception).

I know I could copy the list to a temporary list and enumerate that, but I actually want the list to grow as a user selects more (and this will happen whilst the first note is playing etc).

psuedo logic as is:

```
onClick()
{
 Queue.Add(theClickedNote)
 Queue.Play() <-- on another thread
}

Play()
{
 if(Playing==true){return ;}

 foreach(note theNote in Queue)
 {
  Note.Play();
  Queue.Remove(theNote);
 }
}
```

As you can see in the above, each Click event adds a note to the Queue and then invokes a play method on the queue.

the queue enumerates the notes and plays each one in turn before removing the note

I hope I have explained what I am trying to do clearly?

Comment: Is Queue a `List<T>` or a `Queue<T>`? Looks like a `List<T>` but your variable name is confusing and you only showed pseudocode...

Comment: sorry, there is a lot of code hence the psuedo, the Queue is a list<T>.... what is a Queue<T> dare i ask without googling

Comment: What you are looking for is called the `producer and consumer` pattern...

Comment: I looked at Queues and they have the same problem, i cannot add to the queue whilst enumerating it...

Comment: @DanielGwalter don't enumerate the queue. just dequeue each item in turn. Check out ConcurrentQueue<T> if you can use .Net 4.

Comment: @Mikez with ConcurrentQueue can i add to it whilst its being enumerated?

Comment: @DanielGwalter you can but, not in the way you want. GetEnumerator takes a snapshot of the queue so it will not reflect updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this can be used with `ConcurrentQueue<T>` in .Net 4.

```
ConcurrentQueue<Note> Queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Note>();

void onClick()
{
  Queue.Enqueue(theClickedNote);

  // start Play on another thread if necessary
}

void Play()
{
  if (Playing) return;

  Note note;
  while(Queue.TryDequeue(out note))
  {
     note.Play();
  }
}
```

ConcurrentQueue is thread-safe, so no locking needs to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a List you should use a real Queue
Then your code will look like this:

```
    Queue<Note> queue = new Queue<Note>();
    void onClick()
    {
        queue.Enqueue(note);
    }

    void Play()
    {
        if (Playing == true) { return; }

        while (queue.Peek() != null)
        {
            var note = queue.Dequeue();
            note.play();
        }
    }
```

This code isn't thread safe so you should add locks on the queue but this is the general idea.

Comment: `Peek` throws if the queue is empty. You should check the count.

Comment: that did the job, if you get a moment could you show me a bit about Lock's in the above example ... (locks are new to me)

Comment: mike z had the better solution using ConcurrentQueue as it's thread safe. If you want to add locks to my solution just surround the queue.enqueue and queue.dequeue method calls with a lock(queue) block. It will look something like lock(queue){ queue.enqueue(note); }

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by mike z, use the [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) added in .NET 4.0

Along with the other concurrent collections, this queue allows you to add / remove items asynchronosly + work with a snapshot of the underlying collection, by using the GetEnumerator method and iterating with it.
Notice you still might need to deal with different situations, such as queue being empty, this can be solved via the [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287085.aspx), which take method will block the thread as long as the collection is empty